# What is going on with Gnome icons in the status bar?

Tags: gnome, icons

I recently upgraded to Fedora 32, and ever since, the icons in the top bar have been shifted down slightly.

[image: Reference image]

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: If you reset dconf (`mv ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/user.bak` followed by a restart of the graphical environment), does the top bar fix itself?

Comment: That does it! Thank you much. Answer with this, and I'll accept for you!

Comment: I'm glad that sorted it! Graphical problems with Gnome updates have been becoming more and more frequent lately, hopefully things calm down when people have less free time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever Gnome3 breaks in a mystical way (which happens about once every two months for me on Debian/sid), you can reset the graphical configuration with

```
mv ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/user.bak
```

If you want to restore it again later, use

```
rm ~/.config/dconf/user; mv ~/.config/dconf/user.bak ~/.config/dconf/user
```

Comment: Very good to know. Was weird behavior, I've never encountered it before. I thank you for your help.